# Wordpress automatic plugin update

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I am developing plugin. Currently my plugin has 1.0 version. If in future I will update my plugins with new version 1.1 , so how can user get message like below image

[image]

**How to compare current version with new version.**

```
I have stored my current version in database.
```

I have googled it. But didn't find any perfect solution.

Comment: You cannot that that exact message because that message comes from the WordPress.org plugin repo.  So unless your plugin is in that repo, you won't get that exact message.  You can however show that type of message elsewhere like in the header on top..etc..

Comment: So what will be happend, if I will update my plugins with new version in worpress.org plugin repo? Will Wordpress directly detect and give that message?

Comment: Yes if you put your plugin in the WP repo, you don't need to code that part, it will automatically show it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if exactly what you're looking for, but [Advanced Custom Fields](http://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) has a custom update message.

[image]

Checking its code, it uses:

```
add_action( 'in_plugin_update_message-' . $hook, array($this, 'in_plugin_update_message'), 10, 2 );
```

The `in_plugin_update_message()` callback method it's not exactly simple and worth a [detailed look](https://github.com/elliotcondon/acf/blob/master/core/controllers/upgrade.php#L105). Note that it only works if the plugin is active.